# How to prevent ASP.NET from rendering an additional span with aspNetDisabled around a disabled checkbox?

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

In earlier versions of ASP.NET Microsoft used to render the `disabled = "disabled"`attribute for your controls. However, since the HTML 4.01 specification, the disabled attribute is not valid anymore for each type of web control. It is still valid for `input`, but not anymore for `span`.

So what they've added a style class (in CSS) which is set to controls when they are disabled. This is also the case with any controls in a diabled control. By default, this style class is called `aspNetDisabled`. I know you can change it's name by setting a static property `DisabledCssClass` on the root class `WebControl`.

BUT, a more annoying situation arises for checkboxes. When you disable checkbox ASP.NET renders a `span` around you checkbox with the defined style class on it, such as below.

```
<span disabled="disabled">
    <input id="ctl00_UsecaseContent_ctl01_ctl01_bCVbox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$UsecaseContent$ctl01$ctl01$bCVbox" checked="checked">
</span>
```

We are using Bootstrap as our UI framework, and on top of that a checkbox specific framework [https://github.com/flatlogic/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox][1]. Works fine. However, when I disable my checkbox ASP.NET's additional `span` breaks the structure of my HTML checkbox control hierarchy. As a consequence, the Javascript from awesome-bootstrap-checkbox doesn't handle its behaviour anymore.

So my question is: how can I prevent ASP.NET from rendering this horrible additional 'span'?

Comment: I've added the microsoft reference to my given answer - there is a good explanation of this behaviour

Answer (score 8):

instead of setting `Enabled="false"`

(i.e. `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:CheckBox>`)

set it from code behind like this:

```
chkBox1.InputAttributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

make sure you're using the **InputAttributes** and not the **Attributes**

Answer (score 4):

By setting the `DisabledCssClass` to `null` or `Nothing` you should be able to prevent the entire span from being rendered.

At least, that is working for me in .NET 4.5.2

Answer (score 2):

**.NET 4.0 and above:**

If you want to change the default behaviour e.g. for every `Checkbox` on every page, you have to set in your *Global.asax* file this property

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.DisabledCssClass = null;
}
```

or if you only want to set it for a particular page e.g. `foo.aspx`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox.DisabledCssClass = null;
}
```

this will change the way ASP.Net renders this control in case of `Enabled = false`
from

```
<span disabled="disabled">
    <input id="foo" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="ctl00$foo" disabled="disabled">
</span>
```

into

```
<input id="foo" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$foo" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.disabledcssclass)

---

side note: this can also be set for other or all webcontrols

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.DisabledCssClass = null;
```

Comment: I didn't test it, but if my understanding of static properties (and my reading of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.disabledcssclass?view=netframework-4.8)) is correct, then setting `CheckBox.DisabledCssClass` will *actually* set `WebControl.DisabledCssClass`, and, thus, change the property for *all* types of controls rather than only checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters.WebControlAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.adapters.webcontroladapter(v=vs.110).aspx) to modify render result.

```
public class CheckBoxAdapter: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters.WebControlAdapter
    {

        private CheckBox _control;

        public new CheckBox Control
        {
            get
            {
                return _control;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            _control = (CheckBox)base.Control;
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            //here you can do what ever you want...

            .....

            writer.WriteBeginTag("input");
            writer.WriteAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            writer.WriteAttribute("name", Control.GroupName);
            writer.WriteAttribute("id", Control.ClientID);            

            ....
        }

}
```

Notice that our ASP.NET code is exactly as you would normally make a CheckBox. So now we need to tell our web application "when" it should use our code to render instead of using the default rendering. To do this, we are going to use a "browser" file. So first, add the "App_Browsers" folder to your ASP.NET web application. Now you'll need to add a browser file. Name it like "All.browser" but the name of the file doesn't really matter as long as it ends with the ".browser" extension. The contents of your file should look like this:

```
<browsers>
   <browser refID="Default">
       <controlAdapters>
           <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox" adapterType="CheckBoxAdapter" />
       </controlAdapters>
   </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: You don't really need this adapter to do what you intend to do.  You can just create your own control inherited from Web control e. g. and implement it there. That's easier.

Comment: @aahoogendoorn yeam, it's ok.. in some cases, but in general, u can not use third party controls with same behavior

Comment: I know. In this case I've built one myself. Will probably add the code to StackOverflow soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* remove the relative spam involving inputs disabled */
$('input[type="checkbox"]').parent('.aspNetDisabled').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var cssClass = $this.attr('class');
    /* add the spam css in input and remove span */
    $this.children('input[type="checkbox"]').addClass(cssClass).unwrap()
         /* add extra css on label (optional) */
         .parent('label[for],span').first().addClass('css-input-disabled');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* remove the relative spam involving inputs disabled */
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').parent('.aspNetDisabled').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var cssClass = $this.attr('class');
    $this.children('input[type="checkbox"]').addClass(cssClass).unwrap().parent('label[for],span').first().addClass('css-input-disabled');
  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS Example */
.css-input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.css-input input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.css-input input:focus + span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.css-input input + span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.css-input input + span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
.css-input-disabled {
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.css-checkbox {
  margin: 7px 0;
}
.css-checkbox input + span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.css-checkbox input + span:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 18px;
  content: "\f00c";
  text-align: center;
}
.css-checkbox:hover input + span {
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.css-checkbox-primary input:checked + span {
  background-color: #5c90d2;
  border-color: #5c90d2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Generate from asp.net -->
<label for="CheckBox1" id="Label4" class="css-input css-checkbox css-checkbox-primary">
  <span class="aspNetDisabled">
    <input id="CheckBox1" 
           type="checkbox" 
           checked="checked" 
           disabled="disabled">
  </span>
  <span></span>Disabled
</label>
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer!

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you added some explanation and links to documentation, so the original poster and other users can actually learn from it.